# openlayers vector feature get pixel position

Tags: openlayers

What is the fastest way to get the pixel coordinates of a OpenLayers.Feature.Vector? I mean, I want to get the pixel  (top,left) position relative to map container of a already drawn feature, if possible without calculations because performance improvements.

Thanks & regards, Rafael.

Comment: are you using version 2 or 3?

Comment: Do you mean top left pixel coordinates of the bounding box?

Comment: Also, how do you want to get it, with a SelectFeature control, on the drawend event when creating or some other way?

Comment: I'm using OLv2 and for performance I would like to access to the (cx, cy) pixel position of the drawn VectorFeature. Im using SVG.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In ol3:

```
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
var coordinate = geometry.getCoordinates();
var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
```

In OL2:

```
var geometry = feature.geometry;
var coordinate = new OpenLayers.LonLat(geometry.x, geometry.y);
var pixel = map.getPixelFromLonLat(coordinate);
```

A few prerequisities: the feature must be point, otherwise geometry.getCoordinates() returns an array of coordinates and you need to choose one. The other should be pretty obvious but I'll mention it anyway: variable map is an instance of ol.Map or OpenLayers.Map respectivelly

Comment: If he wants to get the top left, you can also do, var bounds=geom.getBounds() and then get left, and top, from the bounds object.

Comment: I don't know how to use bounds.left & bounds.top because it don't change on zoom change. I have to go throw an array of 3000-5000 features in the worst case. So I was looking for the fastest way to access (cx, cy).

Comment: You can always store it as an attribute of the polygon when you create or modify it and then look it up, rather than recalculating it.

Comment: @JohnBarça Not a bad idea, but you need to consider how often you would access those coordinates. Your proposal could result in the coordinates being calculated more often than if you only calculate them when you need them. Just saying it's use-case-specific.